# Legalities of installing OSX on VMware Workstation?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, vmware-workstation

I have recently installed OSX Snow Leopard on VMware Workstation. Although I have legally purchased a copy of Snow Leopard, I needed to use a downloaded set of files including a darwin file to actually install it in VMware on my custom built PC. Is this legal? Would Apple try to come after me for having used a downloaded copy of some of the files, despite my having actually bought the product?

One reason I ask is because I am trying to run Rails in my virtualized OSX, and it looks like getting XCode in the app store now requires me to buy Lion. I am willing to buy a copy of Lion in the app store of my virtual OSX Snow Leopard, but am unsure of whether Apple will see this, realize my copy uses downloaded files, and do something about it. What do you suggest?

Comment: In my experience, the answer to any question that starts "Would apple come after me" is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this section from [Mac OS X's EULA](http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/):

> B. License from Mac App Store or on Physical Media. If you obtained a
>   license for the Apple Software from the Mac App Store or on
>   Apple-branded physical media, then subject to the terms and conditions
>   of this License and as permitted by the Mac App Store Usage Rules set
>   forth in the App Store Terms and Conditions
>   (http://www.apple.com/legal/itunes/ww/) (“Usage Rules”), you are
>   granted a limited, non-transferable, non-exclusive license:
>
> (i) to download, install, use and run for personal, non-commercial
>   use, one (1) copy of the Apple Software **directly on each Apple-branded
>   computer** running Mac OS X Snow Leopard or Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server
>   **(“Mac Computer”)** that you own or control;
>
> (iii) to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or
>   instances of the Apple Software within virtual operating system
>   environments on each **Mac Computer** you own or control that is **already
>   running the Apple Software.**